# Jquery validator plugin doesn't validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

My validator doesn't work. It adds class "valid" when it's not. I am not sure if i used submit correctly but cannot make it work for hours now. Can anybody help this ?

This is my js code

```
$("#codeForm").validate({
        rules : {
            kapakCode: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlenght:8
            }
        },
        messages : {
            kapakCode: {
                required: "Bu alanı doldurmalısın.",
                minlenght: "Kapak altı kodunu eksik veya hatalı yazdın.",
                maxlenght: "Kapak altı kodunu eksik veya hatalı yazdın."
            }
        }
    });
```

And my form is:

```
<form id="codeForm">
                        <ul class="lightContentList">
                            <li>
                                <span>Enter the code</span>
                                <div class="inputDiv">
                                    <input id="kapakCode" placeholder="ör. D85C12Z5" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img class="captchaTest" src="img/captchaPlaceHolder.png">
                            </li>
                            <li><!--<a class="button greyBtn" id="formSubmit" href="javascript:;">DEVAM</a>--> <input type="submit"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery validate plugin matches the rules against the `name` attribute of the elements, not the `id`. You have no `name` in your `<input>`. Change it to:

```
<input id="kapakCode" name="kapakCode" placeholder="ör. D85C12Z5" type="text">
```